# C: Does the address operator (&) produce a pointer (address + type) or just an address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Most of what I've read about the address operator, `&`, says it's used to get just that - an address. I recently heard it described differently, though, as producing a full-fledged pointer.

Given the following C code,

```
int i1 = 5;
int *p1;

p = &i1;
```

my understanding is that `p1` references the int `5` by storing the address where `i1`'s data is stored and remembering that the data in that location is to be interpreted as an `int` (which dictates how many bytes to read and how to interpret the read data).

Does the address operator yield both the address and the "type-awareness", or is the type-awareness just implicit since `p1` was declared to be an `int` pointer?

One of the things that got me wondering about this was seeing code like:

```
void myFunc(int *ptr);

int i = 5;
myFunc(&i);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` operator simply returns a pointer to its operand. If its operand was an `int` the resulting type will be `int*`. If its operand was an `int*` the resulting type will be `int**`. For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
  int a;
  int b;
  int d;
};

int main ( ) { 
    struct test foo = { 0, 0, 0 } ; 
    printf( "%lu\n", (unsigned long)(&foo + 2) - (unsigned long)&foo );
}
```

Outputs 24 on my machine because the `sizeof(struct test)` is 12, and the type of `&foo` is known to be `struct test *`, so `&foo + 2` calculates an offset of two `struct test`s.

Answer (score 3):

While you're right that the type of `&i1` is `int*`, I think you're assigning too much weight to that idea. I wouldn't describe anything in C as "type-awareness" and there's definitely no "remembering that the data in that location is to be interpreted as type `int`". C types exist only at the source level and not after compilation.

This may be clearer in an example with union:

```
union something {
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

now if you have a variable `x` of type `something`, you can have `&x.a` of type `int*` and `&x.b` of type `char*`, but they're pointing at the same address.

Comment: I think the understanding that types are a precompilation concept will help me here. This was helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i1` has type `int`, so the expression `&i1` takes the address of an `int`, yielding an expression of type `int *`.  This expression is then assigned to `p1`, which is also of type `int *`.

So now `p1` points to the memory location of `i1`, so the expression `*p1` will be `5`.