# C program to do malloc and free on list of variable strings with char**

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free, c-strings

To allocate and free a single string in C, I do the following:

```
char[10] stringToCopy = "CopyString";
int length = strlen(stringToCopy) + 1;
char* CopiedString = malloc(length);
strcpy(CopiedString, stringToCopy, length);
printf("DatabasePath=%s\r\n", CopiedString);
free(CopiedString);
```

In my program, I need to copy such strings to a **char**** datatype. I need help in writing such a program. I am using a third party API which has a structure with this **char**** field entry.

I am not aware of how to **allocate** memory to this datatype and then copy the **CopiedString** into a list of such values. And also how to **free** the value after usage.

Comment: You can use `&CopiedString`

Comment: Hi @Myousefi, can you share some code sample usage please

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702112/)

Comment: `char[10] stringToCopy = "CopyString";` this is wrong. It should be `char  stringToCopy[10] = "CopyString";`

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula .. and as the `char` array `stringToCopy ` later on in the code shown is used as C-string it has to be `char stringToCopy[11]`. Mind the `0`-terminator!

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory:

```
char **arr = malloc(r * sizeof(char *)); 
for (i=0; i<r; i++)
{        
  arr[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(char)); 
}
```

Freeing memory:

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++)
{        
   free(arr[i]); 
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: @Ganesh Kamath I hope, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: What to do if **r** is unknown while allocating memory? Also, where is C getting assigned to arr[i]. I think just memory for C is getting set to arr[i]?

Comment: You might be having an idea on the maximum value, so assign some max value, and then `realloc` based on requirement

Comment: Yes, we are alloting memory to `arr[i]` ,

Comment: If you just need only one, then put `r = 1` and `c = 1`

Comment: Okay, in the question I have given 1 string. Can you show me how to set that string to **arr. Is it like arr[i] = &CopiedString; ?

Comment: `char **arr = &CopiedString` .  `arr` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Since, `CopiedString` is of type `char*`  and it's address should be stored in `char **`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not aware of how to allocate memory to this datatype ....

Follows is a useful C idiom for allocating.

```
size_t number_in_array =  ...;
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * number_in_array);
if (ptr == NULL) {
  puts("Allocation failed");
} else {
  puts("Success");
  // Use ptr
  free(ptr):  // **
}
...
free(ptr): // **
// ** free(ptr) in 1 of 2 places.
```

Notice there is **no** need to code the type of the pointer in the allocation: `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * number_in_array);`.  This is easier to code right, review and maintain than attempting to code the type.

---

> ...  then copy the CopiedString into a list of such values.

You already have good code to form a copied string.  Make a helper function.  Below is OP's with some improvements.  Also research the common `strdup()` function.

```
char *my_strdup(const char *stringToCopy) {
  size_t size = strlen(stringToCopy) + 1;
  char* CopiedString = malloc(size);
  if (CopiedString) {
    memcpy(CopiedString, stringToCopy, size);
  }
  return CopiedString;
}
```

---

> And also how to free the value after usage.

```
size_t number_in_array = 3;
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * number_in_array);
if (ptr == NULL) {
  puts("Allocation failed");
} else {
  ptr[0] = my_strdup("Hello");
  ptr[1] = my_strdup(" ");
  ptr[2] = my_strdup("World");
  // Use ptr (could check for ptr[] allocation failures first)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < number_in_array; i++) {
    free(ptr[i]);
  }
  free(ptr):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strdup to create malloced string in c.

char ** presult = NULL;

for double pointer "presult" we can assign data like this.

```
    if (presult) {
        *presult = strdup("CopyString");
    }
```

Sample code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int copy_data(char ** p) {
       if (p) {
           *p = strdup("Test data");
       }
       return 0;
    }

    int main () {
       char * p = NULL;
       copy_data(&p);
       if (p) {
           printf("daat : %s\n", p);
           // free if not used
           free(p);
           p = NULL;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below program which explains how to allocate memory for `char**` and also how to `free` the same.

Comments are in lined for understanding, please get back in case of any clarification needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 5
#define MAX_LEN_OF_STRING 50

void printStrings_array(char ex_strings[][MAX_LEN_OF_STRING], int nstrings);
char** allocMemForStrings(int nStrings);
void printStrings_ptr(char** strings, int nStrings);

int main()
{

    // example list of string for which we are going to allocate memory and store in char**
    char ex_strings[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][MAX_LEN_OF_STRING] = 
                                                {
                                                "This is the First String",
                                                "This is the Second String",
                                                "This is the Third String",
                                                "This is the Fourth String",
                                                "This is the Fifth String",
                                                };
    
    printf("contents of char[][] \n");
    printStrings_array(ex_strings, NUMBER_OF_STRINGS);

    // list_of_strings is a variable which points to list of strings
    char** list_of_strings = NULL;

    // allocating memory for list of strings
    if ( list_of_strings = allocMemForStrings(NUMBER_OF_STRINGS))
    {
        int i = 0;
        printf("got %p for list_of_strings\n", (void*)list_of_strings);
        while(i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS)
        {
            size_t len = strlen(ex_strings[i])+1;
            
            // allocate memory for each string as per its length
            list_of_strings[i] = malloc(len);
            printf("got %p for string %d\n", (void*)list_of_strings[i], i);
            memset(list_of_strings[i], 0, len);
            strncpy(list_of_strings[i], ex_strings[i], len);
            i++;
        }
        printf("contents of char** \n");
        printStrings_ptr(list_of_strings, NUMBER_OF_STRINGS);
        
        // free ing the memory for char **
        // first we need to free the memory for each of the strings pointed by the list_of_strings variable.
        i = 0;
        while(i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS)
        {
            printf("\n freeing %p ", (void*)list_of_strings[i]);
            free(list_of_strings[i]);
            list_of_strings[i] = NULL;
            i++;
        }
        //now free the list_of_strings pointer 
        printf("\n finally freeing %p ", (void*)list_of_strings);
        free(list_of_strings);
        // to avoid dangling pointers, its best practice to set the pointers = NULL after free.
        list_of_strings = NULL;
        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("cannot allocate memory for strings\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void printStrings_array(char ex_strings[][MAX_LEN_OF_STRING], int nstrings)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< nstrings;i++)
        printf(" %s\n", ex_strings[i]);
}

void printStrings_ptr(char** strings, int nStrings)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< nStrings;i++)
        printf(" %s\n", strings[i]);

}

char** allocMemForStrings(int nStrings)
{
     // need to have memory to store nStrings
     return malloc(nStrings * sizeof (char*));
}
```

Comment: On the namings: A `char*` is **not** a "string", but just a pointer (to `char`), nothing more and nothing less!

Comment: @alk, thanks!! I always have problem with naming variables, i will keep that in mind.