# why when a function takes a pointer, then we pass the address of a specific variable, and not a pointer?

Tags: c++

for example :

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
     some code///
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    
    foo(&x);
}
```

but not this :

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
     some code///
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;

    int *ptr = &x 

    foo(ptr);
}
```

I read articles about this, but everything that says there is that "we are passing the address", but not a pointer, I can not understand why, please tell me

Comment: A pointer value is the address. Your `int* ptr = &x; foo(ptr)` example is valid. Although the second example isn't as you are dereferencing the pointer and as such passing the `int` value.

Comment: `foo(ptr);` will work just fine, but needlessly declares a variable.  "The address of an object" usually means "A pointer to an object".

Comment: The result of e.g. `&x` *is* a pointer. It's a pointer to the variable `x`. It's type will be (in this case) `int*`.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702112/c-does-the-address-operator-produce-a-pointer-address-type-or-just-an-a. Short answer: "The & operator simply returns a pointer to its operand"

Comment: The term of a "pointer to `x`" is ambiguously used as the address of `x` (i.e. `&x`) or a variable `y` (of type `X*` if `x` was of type `X`) holding that address: `X* y = &x`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. A pointer is an address and vice versa (in the contexts you are referring to.)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I correctly understood that the address of the transmitted object already implies a pointer to my object?

Comment: @egor There is no difference in C++. "Pointer to" and "address of" are different terminology for the same idea. Modern C++ favors the "pointer to" terminology, but both are well understood.

Comment: I sort of figured it out, thanks

Comment: "address of" is an rvalue expression. Pointers are lvalues that can contain addresses. C always passes by value: you pass an address rvalue argument to a pointer lvalue parameter when calling a function, that's all.

Comment: A pointer is a variable (or temporary) that hold a value.  The value that held by a pointer is an address.  Hence `int* ptr = &x;` means a pointer assigned to the value of the address of x.  Since C++ is strongly typed (mostly), it's not just a generic pointer, but in particular an int pointer (`int*`).  The two other categories of pointers in C++ are function pointers and member pointers.

Comment: what does `int*` mean?is it a pointer to what?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is fine(legal/valid) because variable `ptr` is a pointer meaning it holds the address of an int(in this case). And this is exactly what `foo` expects as the type of its parameter.

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
    // some code///
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;

    int *ptr = &x;//ptr is a pointer to an int 
    
    foo(ptr);//this works because foo expects a pointer to an int

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example (after the modification)

```
int *ptr = &x 
foo(ptr);
```

is perfectly valid and does exactly the same as `foo(&x)`. The only difference is that you declare an extra variable of type `int*`. The compiler will typically optimize it away, so there's no real difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer holds the memory address of a variable. If a function takes a pointer, you are actually passing the address of the variable that it is pointing to so passing a pointer is actually passing an address. Both cases are legal and do the same thing.